# Creating Direct Limits and Inverse Limits using Tikz

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I am trying to make something that looks like [image]

I am trying to go from here (works):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}\arrow{rd}
&B \arrow{d}\arrow[leftarrow]{r}
&C \arrow{ld}\\
&D
\end{tikzcd}
```

to here (doesn't work):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}\arrow{rd} \arrow{rdd}
&B \arrow{d}\arrow[leftarrow]{r}
&C \arrow{ld} \arrow{ldd} \\
&D
&E\\
\end{tikzcd}
```

I try many combinations but don't see how the tikz@x-y-z values work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use three columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=4em]
X_{i} \arrow[rr,"f_{ij}"] \arrow[dr,"\phi_{i}"]
  \arrow[ddr,swap,end anchor={[xshift=0.2em]north west},"\psi_{i}"]
&& 
X_{j} \arrow[dl,swap,"\phi_{j}"] 
  \arrow[ddl,end anchor={[xshift=-0.2em]north east},"\psi_{j}"]
\\
& X \arrow[d,"u"]
\\
& Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `end anchor` are just to avoid the arrow ends to be too near to each other.

[image]

Comment: For inverse limit, just dualize, of course. `;-)`